# String is not converting into date according to time zone

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter, xcode6.4, ios8.4

I am receiving date in string form from server and I need to show the date according to my time zone (Indian: GMT +5:30).
Here is my code

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-08-10 11:45:10";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    //Create the date assuming the given string is in GMT
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSLog(@"%@",date);

    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

    //Create a date string in the local timezone
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone].secondsFromGMT];
    NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"date = %@", localDateString);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone].secondsFromGMT];

    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter2 dateFromString:localDateString];

    NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

And the Log is:

```
2015-08-10 11:45:10 +0000 (NSDate)
2015-08-10 11:45:10 (NSString)
date = 2015-08-10 17:15:10 (NSString)
2015-08-10 11:45:10 +0000 (NSDate)
```

My issue is with last log (2015-08-10 11:45:10 +0000)
Why it is not ***2015-08-10 17:15:10***??

Answer (score 0):

The last line prints what it does because you're printing an `NSDate`, and `NSDate` does not have a time zone. It literally has no attribute or internal state that indicates a time zone. Time zones exist only for presenting data to users, commonly as you're doing via `NSDateFormatter`. But if you log the value of an `NSDate` you'll get a GMT string, since the `NSDate` itself has no time zone.